# How to expose vuex store of nuxt app to cypress?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, cypress

I want to create tests for a vuex store with cypress for a project built with nuxt. The problem is that I cannot find a way to expose the store to cypress so that I can dispatch actions from within a test like so (code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194193/7402973)):

```
cy.visit()
cy.window().should('have.property', '__store__')
cy.window().then( win => {
  win.__store__.dispatch('myaction')
})
```

The answer closest to my problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194193/7402973). But this seems to be a valid answer only for a vue.js app built without nuxt, especially since the Nuxt documentation indicates that nuxt has [deprecated what it calls the classic mode](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#classic-mode) for instatiating stores, which is the method used in the refered answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Isn't Cypress an E2E testing framework? Wouldn't this be mixing concerns? Maybe programmatically push the button in the UI to dispatch the action instead?

Comment: Cypress is indeed focused towards writing E2E tests. And I did achieve writing a test in the way you suggest. I should probably mention also at this point that the store action I want to trigger is for user login. But calling for this test, mimicking a user clicking through the application, each time I want to visit a page requiring login would slow down my tests a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in plugin. E.g. create a client only plugin that will set store to window

plugins/exposestore.client.js

```
export default ({store}) => {
  window.__store__ = store
}
```

Comment: Excellent! This answer basically is the solution. But I guess your forgot to add a fat arrow. I tried to edit but the editor requires me to edit at least 6 characters.

export default ({store}) => {
  window.__store__ = store
}

Answer (score 5):

You should expose it in nuxt via client-side plugin:

```
// plugins/cypress.js

const isCypress = typeof window.Cypress !== 'undefined'

export default ({ store }) => {
  if (isCypress) {
    window.store = store
  }
}
```

Then in cypress you can test it:

```
// cypress/integration/example.spec.js

describe('Store', () => {   
  it('Application store is exposed to cypress', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.window().should('have.property', 'store')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

The store is also accessible through the NuxtJS helper, [$nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/$nuxt). You access it in Cypress through the `window`:

```
cy.window()
  .its('$nuxt')
  .then((nuxt) => {
    console.dir(nuxt.$store)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a few days because I was experiencing some sort of race condition between Cypress and my app. Instead of a plugin, I added the browser check into the mounted function of my `layout/default.ts` file:

```
mounted() {
        if (window.frameElement !== null && window.frameElement.id.includes('Your App')) {
            window.store = this.$store;
        }
    },
```

Also keep in mind when verifying that there are two windows in this case: your Cypress window and your app window within Cypress.